# openpyxl read Table to python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to read an excel Table object into python and can't find any syntax for doing so.
It would be useful to read a whole table into e.g. a dict of dicts (I'm trying not to pull in pandas as a dependency for this particular project).
I can't find any way of doing this.

Comment: What hav you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will read through the table row by row, Also you can specify the range

```
import openpyxl  
  
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')  

sheet = wb.active

for i1,i2 in sheet['A1':'B7']:  
    print("{0:8} {1:8}".format(i1.value,i2.value))
```

Output:

```
Student_name        Marks
Tony Stark           47
Loki                 59
Oddin                73
Nick Fury            62
Samaul               75
Peter Parkar         80
```

[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: `sheet['A1','B7']` raises an exception in openpyxl

Comment: Yes, I observed that I have modified the code as it should for you now   .........

sheet['A1','B7'])

for i1,i2 in sheet:  
    print("{0:8} {1:8}".format(i1.value,i2.value))

Comment: Can you try again please replace "sheet['A1','B7']" with sheet['A1':'B7'] it will work. I missed to edit that in the post :)

Comment: I was looking to read a named table object, which may be dynamic in size, rather than a fixed range of cells.

Comment: The edited code still makes no sense because the range isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working as follows:

```
import openpyxl


def all_tables_data(filename: str) -> dict:
    """
    Get values for all tables in a spreadsheet.
    Returns a dict of tables, keyed by table name.
    Table values are given as lists of lists.
    """
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    tables_by_name = {}
    table_worksheets = {}
    for worksheet in workbook.worksheets:
        for table in worksheet._tables:
            tables_by_name[table.name] = table
            table_worksheets[table.name] = worksheet

    def get_vals(table_name: str) -> list:
        worksheet = table_worksheets[table_name]
        cell_range = worksheet[tables_by_name[table_name].ref]
        return [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in cell_range]

    return {table_name: get_vals(table_name) for table_name in tables_by_name}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FILENAME = "my_spreadsheet.xlsx"
    TABLES = all_tables_data(FILENAME)
    print(TABLES)
```

I'm interested in converting tables to dicts.
Often the rows/entries in a table may have >1 key.
Assuming the table has a header row, I also cobbled the code below together.
It can be used to convert a table to a dict of rows, with each row being a dict of values, keyed by the column headers.

```
class WorkbookWithTables:
    def __init__(self, workbook):
        self.workbook = workbook
        self.tables_by_name = {}
        self.table_worksheets = {}
        for worksheet in self.workbook.worksheets:
            for table in worksheet._tables:
                self.tables_by_name[table.name] = table
                self.table_worksheets[table.name] = worksheet

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename):
        _workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        return cls(_workbook)

    def table_to_dict(self, table_name, n_keys=1):
        worksheet = self.table_worksheets[table_name]
        cell_range = worksheet[self.tables_by_name[table_name].ref]
        table_dict = {}
        value_headers = tuple(cell.value for cell in cell_range[0][n_keys:])
        for row in cell_range[1:]:
            if n_keys == 1:
                key = row[0].value
            else:
                key = tuple(partial_key.value for partial_key in row[:n_keys])
            values = {
                value_headers[i]: cell.value
                for i, cell in enumerate(row[n_keys:])
            }
            table_dict[key] = values
        return table_dict


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FILENAME = "my_spreadsheet.xlsx"
    WB = WorkbookWithTables.from_file(FILENAME)
    MY_SINGLE_KEYED_TABLE = WB.table_to_dict("my_single_keyed_table")
    MY_DOUBLE_KEYED_TABLE = WB.table_to_dict("my_double_keyed_table", 2)
```

Comment: With a bit more work, I'm going to develop another function that saves rows in the table as dict entries. This would take an int argument as to the number of keys (assumes the first n columns of each row are a key). The dict key would be a tuple of length n, unless n=1, and the dict values would either be a tuple of the non-key columns, or another dict of those columns keyed by the column header names (if present).

Comment: Please check out the documentation for worksheet tables, this stuff is easier than you think.

Comment: The documentation is very poor and doesn't describe reading from tables clearly. It refers to a worksheet.tables attribute that doesn't exist, for instance.

Comment: Check that the version of the documentation matches what you have installed.